# Perfect graphs are normal graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colorings

Let $G$ be a graph. We call $G$ normal if it admits two partitions: $V(G)=\bigcup \mathcal{I}=\bigcup \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{I}$ is a collection of independent sets and $\mathcal{C}$ is a collection of cliques such that $\forall I\in\mathcal{I},\forall C\in\mathcal{C},C\cap I\neq \varnothing. $

**Theorem** Perfect graphs are normal.

I have seen this result several times referring to *'An extension of the class of perfect graphs'* by J. Korner in 1974. Unfortunately, there is no online version or PDF of the article. I am seeking a copy or direct proof. Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202084/prove-all-perfect-graphs-are-normal